# Cos'era una "pipetta di zucchero"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> In quei giorni c'era poco da fare a Mineo e io aspettavo la festa di Sant’Agrippina e ne parlavo spesso con Angelina nel fresco della mia stalla dove volavano grosse mosche cavalline che si attaccavano alle vesti. La festa arrivava col torronaio di Vizzini che alzava la sua baracca nel centro della piazza e disponeva sul tavolo le **pipette** rosse **di zucchero**, il torrone di ceci e i semi di cocomero.

La mia domanda è su queste "pipette di zucchero" che appaiono in questo testo.
Immagino si trattasse di qualche dolce per bambini. Ho visto questa espressione in alcuni siti web, ma non sono riuscita a trovare cosa fosse. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Credo sia un dolce tipo bastoncino di zucchero candito.... potrebbe essere una cosa tipo questa https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/multi-bastoncino-di-zucchero-candito-colorato-zuccherato-dolce-57959821.jpg